Did anyone challenge the Nazi regime in court?
In 1933, when the Nazi regime was not fully established, were there court cases where people tried to legally challenge illegal actions by the government (like imprisonment without verdict, removing non-Nazi and Jewish people from schools and universities, etc.)?

1924 there was one.

@Trish, H:SE is trying to avoid answers in comments. There is a growing consensus that answers in comments weakens the site. Could you expand on this and develop it into a formal answer?

The book-length answer: https://archive.org/details/hitlersjusticeco0000mlle

Frame challenge. With the Enabling Act of 1933, signed 23 March 1933, there was no "illegal action" to be challenged anymore. The Enabling Act empowered the Chancelor -- Hitler -- to govern by decree, including decrees that violated the constitution, without thematic limits or parliamentary oversight. To say "the Nazi regime was not fully established" by then seems a bit overly optimistic.

@DevSolar Two things: 1. The Enabling Act itself was highly dubious, so someone could have challenged it in court. 2. Many actions of the SA or other Nazi groups were not officially ordered by Hitler, at least not in a formal decree.

@MCW that comment was taken over in migration. Also, the 1924 "Beer Hall Putch" is decidedly before the date of 1933.

@JFabianMeier 1) The Enabling Act might have been "dubious" to some, but it gave Hitler, and by extension the NSDAP / SS / SA, complete control over legislative, judicative, and execututive. There were no mechanisms left to stop the Nazi rule formally. 2) You seem to not understand the Führerprinzip. Not having to rely on direct orders was part and parcel of the whole system. Hitler and his croonies riled up their underlings, and they did their best to be seen favorably by doing what they thought was expected of them. Look at Trump for a parallel. He doesn't have to write orders either...

...they all just try to be on his good side so when he's (gods forbid) re-elected, they will get a part of the cake. Bestowed with immunity and the right to pardon, plus having the SCOTUS in his pocket already, who would you turn to to "challenge him in court"?

@DevSolar Please don't turn your comment into a rant.

@JFabianMeier It is not a rant, but a discussion of the framing of your question. The analogy was to illustrate the inherent issue of futility trying to appeal in a system that has already been undercut. FWIW, Germany is facing a similar issue these days, as do many other countries, where democratic structures prove to be vulnerable to a dedicated power grab.

@DevSolar The question was whether someone tried to go to court, not if it was a good idea.

@JFabianMeier And I pointed out that there was nothing to be challenged, as "the Nazi rule" was legalized by then. Perhaps also have a look at the Gestapa / Gestapo, which by that time had unlimited executive rights as well. Being opposition made you an enemy of the state in 1933.

For a different answer going a bit deeper into legality / Führerprinzip, ref. Was the holocaust legal?

@DevSolar Possible challenges: 1. The Ermächtigungsgesetz is invalid because not the whole of the parliament could take part in it 2. The Ermächtigungsgesetz may allow Adolf Hitler to give written orders to imprison somebody, but not the SA.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

German Wikipedia says about resistance against "Aktion T4" (the killing of mentally disabled people, mostly children) in  1940/41

Als einziger deutscher Richter prangerte Lothar Kreyssig aus
Brandenburg an der Havel die Euthanasiemorde an. Als
Vormundschaftsrichter hatte er bemerkt, dass sich nach einer Verlegung
Nachrichten über den Tod seiner behinderten Mündel häuften. Im Juli
1940 meldete er seinen Verdacht, dass die Kranken massenhaft ermordet
würden, dem Reichsjustizminister Franz Gürtner. Nachdem ihm mitgeteilt
worden war, dass die Mord-Aktion in Verantwortung der Kanzlei des
Führers ausgeführt werde, erstattete Kreyssig gegen Reichsleiter
Philipp Bouhler Anzeige wegen Mordes. Den Anstalten, in denen Mündel
von ihm untergebracht waren, untersagte er strikt, diese ohne seine
Zustimmung zu verlegen. Kreyssig, der damit gerechnet hatte, sofort
festgenommen zu werden, wurde lediglich in den Ruhestand versetzt.
Schließlich sah sich der neu ins Amt berufene Reichsjustizminister
Franz Schlegelberger genötigt, mehr als 90 höchstrangige Justizbeamte
in die Vorgänge einzuweihen. In der Schlegelberger-Konferenz am
23./24. April 1941 gab er eine Stillhalte-Weisung aus, die widerspruchslos entgegengenommen wurde. Neue Ermittlungsverfahren
wurden nicht mehr eingeleitet und ältere Verfahren niedergeschlagen.
Damit waren die Juristen zu „Komplizen der rechtswidrigen Tötung“
geworden.

which Google translates to

Lothar Kreyssig from Brandenburg an der Havel was the only German
judge to denounce the euthanasia murders. As a guardian judge, he
noticed that after a transfer, news of the deaths of his disabled ward
increased. In July 1940 he reported his suspicion that the sick were
being murdered en masse to the Reich Minister of Justice Franz
Gürtner. After he was informed that the murder operation was being
carried out under the responsibility of the Führer's office, Kreyssig
filed a murder complaint against Reichsleiter Philipp Bouhler. He
strictly forbade the institutions in which his wards were housed from
moving them without his consent. Kreyssig, who had expected to be
arrested immediately, was merely forced into retirement.
Finally, the newly appointed Reich Minister of Justice, Franz
Schlegelberger, felt compelled to inform more than 90 highest-ranking
judicial officials of the events. In the Schlegelberger Conference on
23/24. In April 1941 he issued a standstill order, which was accepted
without objection. New investigations were no longer initiated and
older proceedings were quashed. The lawyers had thus become
“accomplices in unlawful killing”

So we know one person by name (Kreyssig) who alarmed the police about ongoing murders, and that there where older proceedings to be squashed, which suggests that other people filed reports as well (and that the police did not think this was legal, even if starting with 1933 there were eugenics laws created that the killings could conceivably justified with. Had the police thought this was justified under the Enabling act or whatever, there would have been no need for clandestine orders to police officers).

I realize that technically this does not answer the question, since the complaints did not make it to court, but I feel reporting to the police still counts as "legal challenge".

(+1) I checked whether any legal challenges occurred in connection with the Rosenstrasse protest of 1943 but based on the account provided by Wikipedia that does not appear to have been the case.
